# Is it possible to log the commands executed on AIX to syslog?

Tags: logging, aix

As above, is there a syslog facility to capture users' activities in AIX? Or can this be done only through shell configurations (i.e. command history)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can enable process accounting

```
touch /var/adm/pacct
chmod 666 /var/adm/pacct
su – adm -c /usr/lib/acct/nulladm /var/tmp/wtmp /var/adm/pacct
su – root -c /usr/sbin/acct/startup
```

<sub>- from [FreeUnixTips](http://freeunixtips.com/2009/02/enable-process-accounting-on-aix/)</sub>

By using the [`acctcom`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds1/acctcom.htm) command you should be able to view a list of programs run by users.

```
Each record represents one completed process. The default display consists of the 
command  name, user name, tty name, start time, end time, real seconds, CPU seconds, 
and mean memory size (in kilobytes). These default items have the following headings 
in the output:

 COMMAND                    START   END    REAL    CPU     MEAN
 NAME    USER    TTYNAME    TIME    TIME   (SECS)  (SECS)  SIZE(K)
```